# Using Reflections for finding the (transitive) subtypes of a class when not all the types in the hierarchy are in the filtered classpath url

Tags: java, reflection, classpath, reflections

I am trying to use the [Reflections](https://code.google.com/p/reflections/) library to obtain all the subclasses of a particular class. I need to filter the search to only the subclasses in a particular classpath url.
This is the code I am using:

```
ConfigurationBuilder config = new ConfigurationBuilder();
config.addUrls(<my_url>);
Reflections reflections = new Reflections(config);
Set<Class<? extends A>> set = reflections.getSubTypesOf(A.class)
```

My problem is the following: Let's assume that class B extends A, and class C extends B. So we have:

```
A <|-- B <|-- C
```

A and B are in a classpath URL different than the one of C. And the url given to reflections is the one of C. Then I would expect C to be in the returned set, and B should not be present since it is in another classpath url.

However, the returned set is empty. C is not in the set of classes returned by reflections, though it is a transitive descendant of A.
If I move B to the same classpath URL of C, then both B and C are returned.
Then I guess the problem is that Reflections by default does not answer (transitive) subclasses if any of the classes in the middle of the hierarchy are not in the filtered url.

My questions is: How can I instruct reflections to answer (transitive) subclasses of a particular class, even if certain classes in the middle of the hierarchy are not in the filtered url (but the subclass itself IS in the filtered url)?.

Answer (score 0):

The point is that transitivity cannot discover if not all relevant urls are scanned. You should know your classpath.

If you don't know all the urls involved you can scan all urls, using

```
ClasspathHelper.forClassLoader()
```

Comment: Hi @zapp, the reason I do not know the classpath beforehand is because what I am developing is a library to be used by third parties. I can infer the classpath of the code invoking my library (playing a bit with the stack trace), so I can transparently add it to the search path of reflections, but I do not see an easy way to include all the relevant class paths needed for clients of my librarues. I think I will have to do it tracking all the urls, but probably this could have a performance impact in my application :( . Thanks for the suggestion anyway!